# How do I get autopygui and pyglet to work together?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, ctypes, pyglet, autopy

Getting a conflict between pyglet and autopygui, when one is running I can't use the other. I found a few things online but no one has posted a resolution to the problem.

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_POINT instance instead of pointer to POINT
```

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/26
https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyglet/issues/559

> This has been fixed together with issue 510 in rev. e46762382a3

Said to be resolved in that link but I'm still having the issue.

https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues/95/pyglet-error-with-lp_point-pyautogui

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, which seems to arise when autopygui makes the mouse click.

If you can import an additional libary, here's a possible workaround: you may use autopygui to locate an image on the screen and another library to make the mouse 'click'. For example:

```
import ctypes
import pyautogui

def click_mouse_at(pos):
    pos_x, pos_y = int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(pos_x, pos_y)
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) 
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0)
    
def get_centre(a_box):
    ''' return centre of an image '''
    return a_box[0]+a_box[2]/2, a_box[1]+a_box[3]/2

an_img_file_path = ..path to your image file..
click_mouse_at(get_centre(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(an_img_file_path)))
```

Tested on Windows10 and seems to work